# Counting problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n\geq\ 1$ be an integer. Consider the interval $[0,L]$ divided into n parts of identical length. n points are chosen at random, one by one, on the interval $[0,L]$ independently one of the other. Find the probability that exactly one point falls in each subinterval.

My attempt: 1. The cardinality of the sample space of the experiment is $(L / n)^n$ 2. the cardinality of the event is $n!$. Then $P(A)=n!/(L / n)^n$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that any point lands on an endpoint of one of the $n$ intervals is zero and can be ignored.

Instead of choosing points from $[0,L]$, note that landing in each of the subintervals is equally likely. So this really is the probability of obtaining all numbers once if we choose $n$ numbers from $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ with replacement.

Hence our answer is
$$\frac{\text{# of permutations of $n$}}{\text{# of strings of $n$ symbols with length $n$}} = \frac{n!}{n^n}.$$